# Understanding "prévenir les secours": to prevent?

Tags: sens, verbes, faux-amis

I noticed this sentence in the Wikipedia page for the French translation of [*Touching the Void*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Mort_suspendue):

> Sans aucune assistance, à part Richard Hawking, un étudiant rencontré sur place, et qui garde leur camp de base **et doit prévenir les secours après un certain temps d'absence**, les deux hommes savent que le moindre problème peut leur être fatal.

From the context, it is clear that it means he must get help if they fail to return, but I read this as "*and he must prevent rescue after a certain period of absence*". What am I missing? Does prévenir have another meaning?

Comment: *prévenir*'s main meaning is *warn, let someone know*, not *prevent*. Have you tried [a dictionary](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/pr%C3%A9venir) before asking?

Comment: Ahhh, thanks I used google translate which assured me that it meant prevent. Lesson learned.

Comment: It's alright :) And just so you know, I don't recommend Google Translate, not because the translations are "bad" but because it gives 1 translation. Most of the times it's more subtle and words have at least 3-4 translations. It's always better to look in a dictionary that gives several of them.

Comment: Google Translate needs context, just like the rest of us... : ***prévenir** les secours* → "to **prevent** the rescue" but *Il doit **prévenir** les secours après un certain temps d'absence* →  He must **warn** the helpers after a certain period of absence.

Comment: This is not a  translation of the English-linked text on Wikipedia. The English text does not contain this sentence as far as I can determine. Where is the English, please?

Comment: @Lambie  Il n'y a pas de texte anglais original à rechercher. Le texte a été rédigé en français et résume la version française du livre en question.

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, j'ai vu la phrase mais alors pourquoi le PO dit "translation"? Par erreur? prévenir les secours for me is: he must inform the rescue services....back into English, inform works better.

Comment: @Lambie The OP talks about *the French translation of Touching the Void*, i.e. about the book named *La mort suspendue*. Yes, *prevenir* can be also translated by *to inform* or *to notify*. The main point is that *prévenir* must **not** be translated by *to prevent* here.

Comment: @jlliagre Why must every comment of mine be hounded to death? The OP claims the WP page is a translation of the French. It isn't. That is a separate issue from the fact of how to translate prévenir. Of course, it isn't prevent. And I still do not know why the OP called this a translation. Do you mind me asking that question??

Comment: Sure, and I answered to that question. The OP doesn't claim the WP page is a translation of the French. Read closer: *the French translation of Touching the Void* doesn't mean *the French translation of the Wikipedia page about Touching the Void*.

Comment: It's all in the preposition "for"; this sense  is a likely possibillity: *used to show **purpose or function***; accordingly "the WP page *dedicated* to the translation …" is the meaning and there is an error; another possibility, equally likely, is this sense of "for": *concerning sb/sth*; if this latter possibility is the one to subscribe to, we are left in the doubt: is it the page about the translation or is it the page involving it. (making it an important part in it) ?  Whatever the choice, the conclusion is that there is either an error or an imprecision in this use of "for".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Teleporting Goat said, *prevenir* means *to warn*. For example:

*I'm warning you: Google Translate sucks.* --> *Je te préviens Google Traducteur est nul.*

Good advice, try to use [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator) instead of Google translate. It's much better!